# Find all items from two different custom lists using LINQ (C#)

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists ...

```
List<ObjectA> listA
List<ObjectB> listB
```

Both have a int property ID, that is unique...

I´d like to get all objects from listA that have `listA[x].ID = listB[x].ID`, using LINQ...

Thanks

Comment: Looking back at this, do you mean you want all of the items in listA which have an item in listB with a matching ID, that are also at the same index as the item in listA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `.Join(...)` function.

In query syntax, it would look something like this:

```
var result = from a in listA
             join b in listB on a.ID equals b.ID
             select new { /* properties you want */ };
```

In standard C# syntax, it would look something like this:

```
var result = listA.Join(listB, a => a.ID, b => b.ID, (a, b) => new { /* properties you want */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
from a in ListA
   join b in ListB on a.ID equals b.ID
   select new { ListAItem = a, ListBItem = b };
```

This will generate a list of anonymous objects each containing the ListA and ListB item where the IDs match.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = listA.Where((x, i) => x.ID == listB[i].ID);
```